# Stack Overflow Android app wrongly thinks that questions are deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I just got a Nice Answer badge for [my answer on "When should I use git stash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537356/2422776). This achievement shows up properly in the new Stack Overflow app (not the old Stack Exchange app), but when I try to click through to the question, I get an error message that the question was deleted:

[image: Question not found error]

As you can see by clicking on the link I posted, the question is very much still there.

Technical details:

- App version: 1.0.1
- Android version: 5.1.1
- Phone Model: Nexus 4

Comment: Repro'd this, the API is giving the app an `item_url` of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537356` for the "Nice Answer" achievement, and the number at the end there is the answer id, not question id. Fixing now for next app update.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi That was quick, thanks!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Are you planning to make an answer so people can see it’s resolved?

Comment: @JF I will once the app update including this is live, trying to get some more fixes in before I submit an app update today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for this is live as of version 1.0.2, available on the Play Store right now (or as soon as it propagates to all the CDN nodes).

Comment: Thanks Kasra! I don't have a recent answer badge to test this with, unfortunately, but I'll come back and confirm the fix when I get one.

Comment: I just got another Nice Answer badge and was able to confirm the fix works just fine. Thanks again!